# RPi's screen starts doing strange things when running a software

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, hdmi, screen, crash

I would like to know if someone could help me with this, when I starts a software like Blender or Sonic Pi my screen begins to freeze and by continuing refreshing the screen I finish with a white screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXm3U.jpg
I actually have a Raspberry Pi 4 model B and the 5inch HDMI LCD screen from Waveshare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that hmdi screen model...

It is cursed for me too.

Make sure you have this at the end of config.txt:

```
# --- added by elecrow-pitft-setup  ---
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_drive=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
display_rotate=0
# --- end elecrow-pitft-setup  ---
```